# pgfplots move axis label together with axis line

Tags: pgfplots, axis

I would like to have the y axis labels of all plots in my document above the y axis line. Usually that is `above origin` but sometimes I have to move the line out of the way. What I am looking for is a method to tie axis line and axis label together, so that they move as if they were one.

#### Attempt

The pgfplots manual (chapter 4.9.10 Moving Axis Lines) states that `axis y line shift` allows to shift the axis line together with all its descriptions, but it does not seem to. The axis line moves but the label (which I consider a description of the axis line) stays in place. Even with `ylabel shift` the label does not move.

#### Quick fix

As a substitute I currently move the axis line to the far left and align the label `north west`. This is not really what I want but I can live with it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.17,
  every axis/.style={
    axis lines={center},               %%% axes at origin by default
    every axis x label/.style={
      at=(current axis.right of origin),
      right,
    },
    every axis y label/.style={
      at=(current axis.above origin),   %%% y axis label above origin by default
      above,
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ylabel={==y==},
    axis y line shift={0.5}, %%% attempt: moves axis line (but not the label)
    ylabel shift={0.5},      %%% attempt: has no effect
    % axis y line={left},                          %%% quick fix
    % ylabel style={at=(current axis.north west)}, %%% quick fix
    ]
    \addplot table {
      -1 -1
       1  1
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The following image shows the output of the code above.
The y label did not move with the y axis line. It is above the origin although it should have moved with the line.

[image: label does not move with axis line]

The next image shows the result of the quick fix. Label '==y==' is above axis line.

[image: axis line far left]

Comment: I do have trouble understanding what you are asking. Can you show the current output and add the intended outout? But maybe it's just me.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've edited my post to make it clearer.

Comment: Will `every axis y label/.style={at=(yticklabel* cs:1), ...` work in all cases?

Comment: @Torbjørn T.  Yes, I think it does. Post it and I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use

```
every axis y label/.style={
   at=(yticklabel* cs:1),
   %...
```

to position the axis label. The `yticklabel* cs` coordinate is described in section 4.9.1 *Placement of axis descriptions* of the `pgfplots` manual. (page 244-45 of the manual for version 1.18.1).